# Call Python function in window action odoo

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I added this python function to 'hr.holidays' model

```
class InheritHrHolidays(models.Model):
_inherit = 'hr.holidays'

def _get_holiday_status_id_domain(self):
    if not self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user'):
        allocate_type = self.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([('name', '=', 'Compensatory Days')], limit=1)
        return [('id', '=', allocate_type.id)]
    elif self.env.user.has_group('hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_user') and not self.env.user.has_group(
            'hr_holidays.group_hr_holidays_manager'):
        allocation_types = self.env['hr.holidays.status'].search([('name', '!=', 'Unpaid')])
        return [('id', 'in', allocation_types.mapped('id'))]
```

I want to call this function in action id="hr_holidays.open_allocation_holidays' to still execute while action running..

```
<record id="open_allocation_holidays" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Allocation Request</field>
        <field name="res_model">hr.holidays</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,kanban,form</field>
        <field name="context">{
            'default_type':'add',
            'search_default_my_leaves': 1,
            'needaction_menu_ref':
            [
                'hr_holidays.menu_open_company_allocation',
            ]
        }</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                Click here to create a new leave allocation request.
            </p>
        </field>
        <field name="domain">[('type','=','add')]</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="edit_holiday_new"/>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_hr_holidays_filter"/>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function in an window action, instead you have to create for example a server action (with code), which then should be called or used by the menu item. In that server action you can use the original window action but manipulated with the domain from your function.

The code for the server actions should be something like this:

```py
action = env.ref('hr_holidays.open_allocation_holidays').read()[0]
domain = model._get_holiday_status_id_domain()
action['domain'] = domain
```

Comment: like this:
    `<record id="dynamic_domain_for_allocation_action" model="ir.actions.server">
        <field name="name">Dynamic Domain For Allocate Action</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="hr_holidays.model_hr_holidays"/>
        <field name="code">action = env.ref('hr_holidays.open_allocation_holidays').read()[0]
domain = model._get_holiday_status_id_domain()
action['domain'] = domain
        </field>
    </record>`

Comment: it doesn't affect

Comment: Have changed the menu item's action too?

Comment: i don't understand ??
i inherit this action from 'hr_holidays' and then updated it as you said 
thanks

Comment: The original action (window; hr_holidays.open_allocation_holidays) is used in an menu item, where the whole action is coming to action (pun intended). You have to change the menu item's action to your server action now.

Comment: i added it but menu item doesn't work is that because it can't see python function
    `<menuitem id="hr_holidays.menu_open_allocation_holidays" parent="hr_holidays.menu_hr_holidays_my_leaves" action="dynamic_domain_for_allocation_action"/>`

Comment: `<field name="state">code</field>` is missing in your server action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205933/discussion-between-omar-ahmed-and-czoellner).